# C# how to apply alternate pattern in a while or for loop between dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have a list/array of dates between (start date)01-03-2021 to (end-date)22-03-2021

I would like to apply an alternate pattern in which for example if its 2/3 pattern, I will get an output like this, based on the dates above:

- 01-03-21 - Red
- 02-03-21 - Red
- 03-03-21 - Blue
- 04-02-21 - Blue
- 05-03-21 - Blue
- 06-03-21 - Red
- 08-03-21 - Red
- 09-03-21 - Blue
- 10-03-21 - Blue
- 11-03-21 - Blue

etc until the end date

you can see there is a pattern.

```
var start = new DateTime(2020, 3, 1);
var end = new DateTime(2020, 3, 22);

int reds = 2, blues = 3;  
DateTime currentDay = start;

while (currentDay <= end)
{

  // Console.WriteLine("***")
}
```

Comment: You could use "for" loop even for date. I think the readibility would be better :-) `for (DateTime current = start; current < end; current = current.AddDays(1))`

Answer (score 1):

The below code creates a Dictionary associating each date to its color.

```
var colors = new [] { "Red", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue" };

var start = new DateTime(2020, 3, 1);
var end = new DateTime(2020, 3, 22);

var colorByDateTime = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();

DateTime current = start;
int dateTimeIndex = 0;
while (current <= end)
{
    colorByDateTime.Add(current, colors[dateTimeIndex % colors.Length]);
    current = current.AddDays(1);
    dateTimeIndex++;
}
```

You could use Linq too. Since you mentioned your dates were in a collection:

```
var colors = new [] { "Red", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue" };

Dictionary<DateTime, string> colorByDateTime = dateTimes
    .Select((dt, i) => new { dt, i })
    .ToDictionary(e => e.dt, e => colors[e.i % colors.Length]);
```

Should produce the same dictionary.

[Link to Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hDnSVR).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a counter that you increment for each day, then you can use the mod operator to test for the colour:

```
        var i = 0;
        while (currentDay <= end)
        {

            // ....

            if (i % 5 < 2 )
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Red");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Blue");
            }
            i++;

            // ......
        }
```